# python asyncio - multicast receiver

Tags: python, udp, python-asyncio, multicast

I'd like to ask for advice about how to receive UDP multicast with asyncio and dynamically control its reception.

I run a UDP multicast Receiver which listens to commands coming from the management client. The function Receiver.start_mgmt() starts listening on localhost:port and starts the infinite async loop.

If any command (read a new multicast) from the client comes, the Reciever.handle_command() function handles the command and creates the multicast reader coroutine in Receiver.open_multicast(). 
I want to add the multicast coroutine to the existing infinite loop - it works with the asyncio.ensure_future(...) but I get `RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future.`

Eventually, I want to add and remove multicasts while the loop is running and seamlessly receive UDP datagrams from various multicasts.

The Receiver:

```
import socket
import asyncio
import struct
import json

class MulticastServerProtocol:
    # Protocol Factory demanded by loop.create_datagram_endpoint

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        # handle the data received from multicast
        print(f'Received datagram...', data)


class Receiver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def start_mgmt(self):
        coro_mgmt_server = asyncio.start_server(self.handle_command,'127.0.0.1', 8899, loop=self.loop)
        self.mgmt_server = self.loop.run_until_complete(coro_mgmt_server)
        self.run_receiver()

    def run_receiver(self):
        try:
            self.loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.loop.stop()
            self.loop.close()

    def close_mgmt(self):
        self.mgmt_server.close()
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.mgmt_server.wait_closed())

    # called when anything from the management client comes
    async def handle_command(self, reader, writer):

        data = await reader.read()
        command = json.loads(data)

        print('Received command', command)

        if command['type']=='channel':
            if command['action']=='add':
                self.open_multicast(command)

    def open_multicast(self, channel):

        addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(channel['address'], None)[0]

        sock = socket.socket(addrinfo[0], socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        group_bin = socket.inet_pton(addrinfo[0], addrinfo[4][0])

        if addrinfo[0] == socket.AF_INET: # IPv4
            sock.bind(('', channel['port']))
            mreq = group_bin + struct.pack('=I', socket.INADDR_ANY)
            sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

        # create coroutine
        listen = self.loop.create_datagram_endpoint(MulticastServerProtocol, sock=sock)

        # trying to add coroutine to the infinite loop
        transport, protocol = asyncio.ensure_future(listen, loop=self.loop)


receiver = Receiver()
# start server to receive commands from the client
receiver.start_mgmt()
receiver.close_mgmt()
```

The client works:

```
import socket
import struct
import asyncio
import json

async def tcp_client(message, loop):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8899, loop=loop)
    writer.write(json.dumps(message).encode())
    writer.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Send command to read new multicast
msg = {'type':'channel', 'action':'add', 'name':'channel1', 'address':"239.255.123.45", 'port':12345}
loop.run_until_complete(tcp_client(msg, loop))

loop.close()
```

1. Run the Receiver
2. Run the Client which provides the command, single time
3. Interrupt Receiver

**Output:**

The command from the client comes, it's fine:

```
Received command {'type': 'channel', 'action': 'add', 'name': 'channel1', 'address': '239.255.123.45', 'port': 12345}
```

Then I get the error that I don't know how to get rid of.

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-4' coro=<Receiver.handle_command() done, defined at ./so_mc_receiver_server.py:39> exception=RuntimeError("await wasn't used with future")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./so_mc_receiver_server.py", line 48, in handle_command
    self.open_multicast(command)
  File "./so_mc_receiver_server.py", line 71, in open_multicast
    transport, protocol = asyncio.ensure_future(listen, loop=self.loop)
RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
```

Then I receive the multicast data, it's fine.

```
Received datagram... b'\x15\x00j\xf5\x1d1C\x03&1\'
Received datagram... b'\x15\x00q\xf5\x1d1C\x83&1\xe0\x11'
```

Then I get another error when stopping the program Ctrl+C

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./so_mc_receiver_server.py", line 78, in <module>
    receiver.close_mgmt()
  File "./so_mc_receiver_server.py", line 36, in close_mgmt
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.mgmt_server.wait_closed())
  File "/home/anaconda38/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 591, in run_until_complete
    self._check_closed()
  File "/home/anaconda38/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Server.wait_closed' was never awaited
```

Thanks for any advice how to receive multicasts with asyncio and dynamically control the reception.

Comment: The line `transport, protocol = asyncio.ensure_future(listen, loop=self.loop)` doesn't make sense - `ensure_future` returns a future, not a transport/protocol pair. And you're not even _using_ the variables, so what's the point of trying to assign to them?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I should have awaited this:
        protocol, transport = await asyncio.get_event_loop().create_datagram_endpoint(MulticastServerProtocol, sock=sock)

Complete gist here: https://gist.github.com/petrdvor/e802bec72e78ace061ab9d4469418fae